# How to cast an object to a List

Tags: c#, reflection

I have an object which is actually a List. I have a string what the element type is but I don't know how to cast the object to a List? Here is some code depicting my problem.

```
class Data
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public List<double> Values { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Data d = new Data() { ID = 69, Values = new List<double>() };
    d.Values.Add(1.0);
    d.Values.Add(2.0);

    PropertyDescriptorCollection props = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(Data));
    var propInfo = typeof(Data).GetProperties();

    foreach (var p in propInfo)
    {
        var Value = p.GetValue(d, null);
        var Type = p.PropertyType;

        if (Type.IsGenericType && Type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>))
        {
            // get the element type of a list
            var ElementType = Value.GetType().GetProperty("Item").PropertyType;

            // how to cast to List< "ElementType" > ???
        }
        else
        {
            types.Add( Type.FullName );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you intend to do with it?

Comment: It seems a bit pointless to cast to a List of type which you acquire dynamically - since your code (which is static) can not use this additional type information. If what you wish to do is to access the data as a list, I'd suggest casting to System.Collections.IList.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generics and reflection don't play very nicely. Your best bet is to use the non-generic `IList` API:

```
IList list = (IList)Value;
```

Then you can iterate, access by index, Add, Remove, etc.

Comment: I just need the count but when I try your way I get a compiler error saying IList requires a 1 type argument. I'm using .Net 4. Do I need to add another namespace?

Comment: @chhenning Yes, `System.Collections`